# How to omit the first char of string in Java?

Tags: java, string

Given 2 strings, return their concatenation, except omit the first char of each. The strings will be at least length 1.

Here is my code but I don't know what's wrong with it:

```
public String nonStart(String a, String b) {
       a.substring(1);
       b.substring(1);
       return a + b;
```

there is my code but it does not work at all.

Comment: I'm already posted my own code sorry about that

Comment: This is because String class is inmutable, you can not change it with a.substring(1), instead of this you should assign the result to another String like this String result = a.substring(1);

Comment: Homework stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String`s don't change, so calling `a.substring(1)` *doesn't change `a`*. Instead it creates a brand new `String`.

Going along with your coding style, you need to change which `String`s `a` and `b` are referring to by reassigning them using `a =` and `b =`:

```java
public String nonStart(String a, String b) {
       a = a.substring(1);
       b = b.substring(1);
       return a + b;
}
```

When you do that, `a` now refers to the brand new `String` with one less character in it than the original `a`. `b` now refers to the new version of `b` with one less character.

Then, when you add together the two new `String`s, you get the result you want.

Comment: No, `a` gets declared in the method header: (`public String nonStart(String a, …` ⇐ right here). The `a =` line just changes **which** `String` a is referring to. After that line, `a` doesn't refer to the `String` it started out referring to. It refers to the new, shorter `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the result of the concatenation into another `String`, since `String` objects in Java are inmutable.

```
public String nonStart(String a, String b)
{    
  String S = ""; // new String object
  S += a.substring(1); // concatenation with String a, without first character
  S += b.substring(1); // concatenation with String b, without first character
  return S;
}
```